# Consuming from blocking collection that can have objects re-added

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I am using a blocking collection to store a custom class, Node, which will hold a database connection and a query to run over that connection. The collection is complete before it is consumed from. However if I pull a Node from the collection and try and run it, it may fail, and I would like to re-add it to the collection to be rerun later.

I have two working solutions, but both I don't like either of them and was hoping someone could give me a cleaner solution, or some ideas on how to improve this.

1st:
Parallel.Foreach on the collection, anything that fails gets added to a new blocking collection which is recursively called.

```
Parallel.ForEach(NodeList, node => {
    try {
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(node.ConnectionString)) {
            conn.Open();
            using (NpgsqlCommand npgQuery = new NpgsqlCommand(node.Query, conn)) {
                using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = npgQuery.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        //Do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
            retryNodes.Add(node);
    }
});
retryNodes.CompleteAdding();
NodeList = retryNodes.ToList<Node>();
try {
    ExecuteNodes();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

I don't like this because it means as the original collection gets to the end it is wasting threads waiting for the new collection to be started.

2nd:
Manually start tasks for each item in the collection:

```
int totalToFinish = NodeList.Count;
while (totalToFinish > 0) {
    while (threadsRunning < MaxAllowedThreads && totalToFinish > 0) {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref threadsRunning);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            if (NodeList.Count == 0) {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadsRunning);
                return;
            }
            Node node;
            NodeList.TryTake(out node, 1000);
            if (node.Attempts++ >= RetryAttempts) {
                throw new Exception("Failed after allowed attemps of: " + RetryAttempts);
            }
            try {
                using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(node.ConnectionString)) {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlCommand npgQuery = new NpgsqlCommand(node.Query, conn)) {
                        using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = npgQuery.ExecuteReader()) {
                            while (reader.Read()) {
                                //Do stuff
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref totalToFinish);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                NodeList.Add(node);
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadsRunning);
        });
    }
}
```

This way works a lot better in terms of performance, but has massive overhead on it and I feel like its not a good way to do it.

If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're setting a limit to the retry count in the second algorithm - you can simplify the first algorithm by including this retry loop

```
Parallel.ForEach(NodeList, node => {
    while(true) {
        try {
            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(node.ConnectionString)) {
                conn.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand npgQuery = new NpgsqlCommand(node.Query, conn)) {
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = npgQuery.ExecuteReader()) {
                        while (reader.Read()) {
                            //Do stuff
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break; // break out of outer while loop
        } catch (Exception e){
            node.Attempts++;
            if(node.Attempts >= RetryAttempts) {
                throw new Exception("Too many retries");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah good idea, I was thinking of something similar to this if I couldn't get a clean solution for re-adding to the collection. My only issue with this is that sometimes a failure can occur because of a connection issue that is temporary, and with this method, I will go through all attempts almost instantly in that case. This is why I was hoping to be able to re-add it to the collection so that it will have a gap before it retries. I suppose I could put the thread to sleep in the case of a failure, but then I have sleeping threads that could have just been active in running another node.

Comment: @StefanOrr One option would be to allocate a few more tasks than you have logical cores via the `ParallelOptions` parameter, e.g. if you have 8 logical cores then you would allocate 10 concurrent tasks - that way if one or two tasks are sleeping you won't be losing any parallelism

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked great thank you. I just set the thread sleep time to be dependent on node.Attempts and scaling between a min and max time allowed for sleeping. Thanks heaps, however I will leave the question open for a little while in case someone has a solution directly related to the original question.